# Change background color of a page using php

Tags: php

I have a standard html page so:

```
<html>
<head>..
.
..
and so on
```

and i have a php script linked to that html page with:

```
if blablabla {

change background color;
}
```

does anyone know how to change the background color of my page if the conditions in the if statement are met?

I hope i made this clear, if not, please say which bit is unclear.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: either print out appropriate css or javascript.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

put your `<body>` tag inside the if else

```
if blablabla {

 echo '<body style="background-color:white">';
}
else {
 echo '<body style="background-color:orange">';
}
```

Comment: <body style="background-color: <?php echo ($blablabla) ? "white" : "orange"?>> would be more efficient :-)

Comment: Yep maybe more efficient, but beginners cringe at the sight of ternary operators, perhaps when the OP get's past the stage of "how to change a background color with php" then he may want to look into it :)

Answer (score 4):

It's not necessarily great practice, but it should get the job done:

```
if ( your_conditional ) {
  $styleBlock = sprintf('
    <style type="text/css">
       body {
         background-color:%s
       }
    </style>
  ', $yourColor);
  echo $styleBlock;
}
```

One good (?) thing about this is that with this technique, you can put your `if` statement anywhere - it'll act on the body tag regardless of where you put it.

One caution: if you have additional style rules for the `body` tag's background color farther down your page, those will take precedence over the one from your `if` statement.

Answer (score 2):

here is code that i whant to change background of body

```html
<body bgcolor="<?php echo $name2; ?>">
```