# Change css background color with php

Tags: php, html, css, colors

I'm having a little problem with css.
I have to create a page with a form on which you can set your background-color by means of radio-buttons and a submit button.
But how could I actually change the css background-color in php?

```
<?php
            if (isset($_POST['set'])) {
                $color = $_POST['color'];
            } else {
                $color = "";
            }
        ?>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="Red"
                <?php if($color == "Red") { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>>Red
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="Green"
                <?php if($color == "Green") { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>>Green
            <input type="radio" name="color" value="Blue"
                <?php if ($color == "Blue") { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>>Blue
            <input type="radio" name="kleur" value="Pink"
                <?php if ($color == "Pink") { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>>Pink

            <br>
            <br>

            <input type="submit" name="set" value="SET">
        </form>
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5475498/5513005) can be useful,

Comment: Don't do this on the server side with php. Do this with javascript instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use style css for body tag

```
 <?php
                if (isset($_POST['set'])) {
                    $color = $_POST['color'];
                } else {
                    $color = "";
                }
            ?>
         <html>
         <body <?php echo !empty($color) ? 'style="background:'.$color.'"' : ''; ?>>
            <form method="post" action="">
                <input type="radio" name="color" value="Red"
                    <?php if($color == "Red") { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>>Red
                <input type="radio" name="color" value="Green"
                    <?php if($color == "Green") { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>>Green
                <input type="radio" name="color" value="Blue"
                    <?php if ($color == "Blue") { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>>Blue
                <input type="radio" name="kleur" value="Pink"
                    <?php if ($color == "Pink") { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>>Pink

                <br>
                <br>

                <input type="submit" name="set" value="SET">
            </form>
           </body>
```