# Konva possible to dynamically change the text of a Konva

Tags: javascript, konva

My question is it possible to dynamically change the text of a Konva.text by doble clicking and entering the new text with the keyboard?

Comment: A simple google search will get you many answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475422/change-background-color-of-a-page-using-php/41272179

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Konva has no out-the-box editable Text.

The docs page [suggests](https://konvajs.org/docs/sandbox/Editable_Text.html) placing an editable HTML element on top of your canvas, let the user make edits, then remove it when done. With this approach, your main problem would be to keep the text styles consistent between the Konva element and the DOM element, to some degree. Otherwise, the transition between the two modes might not look truly WYSIWYG-like. However, depending on what you need, this solution might be just close enough.

Another approach would be to create a hidden `textarea`/`input`, capture its events, and fully emulate text interactions, like cursor movements and text selection, on canvas. This would be hard to do properly but could arguably lead to a more seamless UX. In fact, this is what fabric.js does under the hood for its editable text.